# Set custom Jest environment in docblock

Tags: jestjs

Is it possible to set a custom environment via the [docblock syntax](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), or does it just work with `node` and `jsdom` envs?

Eg:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment my-custom-env
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set a custom environment for a single `Jest` test using the [docblock syntax](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

---

If your custom environment is installed as a package in `node_modules` you can just use the module name.

Alternatively, if your custom environment is defined in a file within your project you can use the path to that file (in this case `my-custom-env.js` in the root directory of the project):

```
/**
 * @jest-environment ./my-custom-env
 */
```